# Inserting newlines (\n) into gsub replace arguments

Tags: ruby, regex, variables

I tried to insert newlines into a `gsub` replacement pattern. It works if the replacement is double quoted string literal like `"text\ntext"`, but not if the replacement is a variable. This may be related to how I refer to my replacement strings.

If I do:

```
replace = "\n// some text"
text.gsub!(/#{find}/, replace)
```

it works just fine.

But when the replacement string that contains `\n` is written in a file,

```
\n// some text
```

read via `File.open`, and is stored as a string, then the replacements:

```
text.gsub!(/#{find}/, "#{replace}")
text.gsub!(/#{find}/, replace)
```

insert literal `\n` characters.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\n` is the escape code for newline. `\` escapes *only* work in literal strings included in Ruby source files. When read in from outside sources, `\n` is just the literal characters `\` and `n`.

An easy fix, if you want to be able to specify newlines using `\n` in your input file, is to add

```
replace = replace.gsub('\n', "\n")
```

Before you use `replace`. This replaces literal `\n`'s in `replace` with actual newlines.

Comment: Lovely! I tried pretty much everything _but_ that. Perfect response!

Comment: @BrianD: Glad it helped you!

Comment: Why not `.gsub('\n', "\n")`?